# Tags shown in xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

How come when I populate my textbox with what's in xmlhttp.responseText tags are shown?  It shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>
```

as well as what I want it to show.  Is there a way to make it so that the tags aren't shown?  The Javascript and AJAX code is as follows:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

ADDED-Code for loadTextBox.php is as follows:

```
<?php
---placeholder for correct db login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---placeholder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult = $row->column_1;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult;
echo $textboxValue; 
?>
```

Comment: And the code of your `loadTextBox.php` file?

Comment: I just added the code for it.

Comment: The solution for all ajax problems: jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was unable to reproduce your problem, so I had to improvise slightly to get the same responseText as you.  Anyway, this is what I came up with, please let me know if it doesn't work:

```
var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
doc.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("textbox").value=doc.innerHTML;
```

Replace your current instance of:

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

With that.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Can you explain why your 3 lines are needed as opposed to my 1 line?

Comment: Sure.  As far as I am aware, the text was treated as a plain string, and inserted directly into the textarea.  With this modification, it's inserted into a dom element, and the text of that element retrieved with DOM traversal.